# How to prevent JS code from being parsed/evaluated by compiler?

Tags: javascript, performance, module

I have a module with a lot of JS code in it. Module is created like so:

```
(function (root, factory) {
  // root === window
  root.MyModuleName = factory();
})(this, function () {
  'use strict';
  var MyModuleName = function() {
    // A lot of code here that I don't want to be parsed or evaluated
    // until MyModuleName constructor is executed.
    //
    // For example:
    // var a = { d: 123 };
    // var b = function() { return 45; };
    // this.someMethod = function() { b() + a.d };
    // ...
  };
  return MyModuleName;
});
```

All methods & properties are inside `MyModuleName` closure and (I thought) they should be parsed only after `MyModuleName()` is executed.

After user clicks on some button I create an instance of `MyModuleName` and execute some method:

```
someButton.onclick = function() {
  // I want compiler to parse and evaluate JS code only here
  var myModule = new MyModuleName();
  console.log(myModule.someMethod());
};
```

Even though `MyModuleName` constructor is executed() only after click, code inside it is evaluated when JS file loads (I can see it in Chrome dev tools timeline).

How to make sure compiler evaluates code only after click, not after JS file loads?

Comment: The code must be parsed to check for syntax errors in the whole script, but the code is usually not compiled until the function is called? Not sure what you mean by "evaluate".

Comment: What exactly is your problem that you need to solve by not evaluating code?

Comment: @Bergi, parsing of the script takes a lot of time on mobile, which causes a lag when trying to scroll. Defer attribute on script tag doesn't help much, it just delays the lag. So I'm trying to preload JS file without fully executing/parsing it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The JS engine has to evaluate the code to create the function before it can assign the function anywhere.

Comment: Hm, I thought JIT compiler might help with that. Thank you for answer. I guess I'll need to manually preload JS file via ajax request or "prefetch" link tag.